# Iterate array in bash v.3

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have file.properties, where are keys and values defined:

```
key1=value1 value2 value3
key2=value4 value5 value6
key3=value7 value8 value9
```

I want to load lines from the file to array. I cannot use declare -A to create associative array because of bash 3.

In bash 4 my code is:

```
conf="./file.properties"

init() {
local configiration=$1
if [ -f "$conf" ]
then
    while IFS='=' read -r key value
    do
        configuration[ ${key} ]=$value
    done < "$conf"
fi}
declare -A configuration
init configuration

KEY="key value from file"
#KEY="key1" or KEY="key2" or KEY="key3"
SERVERS=${configuration[ $KEY ]}
```

I want to do the same job in **bash 3**.

```
conf="./file.properties"
init () {
key=()
value=()
if [ -f "$conf" ]
then
    while IFS='=' read -r key value
    do
        key+=("$key")
        value+=("$value")
    done < "$conf"
fi}
init
KEY="key value from file"
#KEY="key1" or KEY="key2" or KEY="key3"
for ((i = 0; i < ${#key[@]}; i++))
    do
    if [ "${key[$i]}" == "$KEY" ]; 
    then
        echo "values: ${value[i]}"
    fi
done
```

In both cases I get the same output, e.g.:

```
value1 value2 value3
```

Is my code for bash 3 correct or something has to be revised?

Comment: When you say `KEY="key value from file"` what will it actually contain? can you provide it so that we can actually test it?

Comment: Also it is not able to reproduce the problem you are claiming, running your `bash v3.0` code  for `KEY="key1"`,`KEY="key2"`,`KEY="key3"` produced output as `values: value1 value2 value3`, `values: value4 value5 value6` and `values: value7 value8 value9` respectively! Isn't that what you wanted to do? What is your problem then?

Comment: If you are just asking if you have correctly simulated an associative array with a pair of indexed arrays, the answer is for the most part, yes.

Comment: I'm just asking if it is correct (not syntactically but logically) or if it goes somehow better. I am no scripting expert

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct to me, as you use an appropriate way to iterate through your arrays considering you just created them prior and know that the arrays' keys will be in `0,1,...,n-1` for your arrays of size `n`. The `array+=(elements)` operator always places `elements` into `array` starting at `array`'s last index + 1.

The only case where I would iterate through an array differently is if it were not guaranteed that the indices are in `[0,n)`. For example:

```
declare -ai roots=();
declare -i x y;
for ((x=0; x<4; roots[x*x]=x,++x)) do :; done;
for y in "${!roots[@]}"; do
    printf 'sqrt(%d) = %d\n' $y ${roots[y]};
done;
```

By expanding the indices of `roots` using [`"${!roots[@]}"`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#metadata)to iterate across it, we get the following output:

```
sqrt(0) = 0
sqrt(1) = 1
sqrt(4) = 2
sqrt(9) = 3
```

In cases like this, we have to avoid the arithmetic `for` loop to avoid something like the following from occurring:

```
$ for((i=0;i<${#roots[@]};++i)); do echo "${roots[i]}"; done;
0
1
```

---

The only change I would make is to use `[[` instead of `[` to perform string comparison, as it is a bash builtin which is safer and more efficient to use in general. Also, I believe you need either a newline or a `;` before your `}` to close your `init` function.